# Node.js: What's a good way to automatically restart a node server that's not responding?

Tags: node.js, express

I've inherited a node.js/Express app that is a bit of a mess. It's regularly and fairly randomly getting stuck and not responding to any request until it is restarted.

I suspect that something within the app is blocking and either getting stuck in a loop or making a request to an external api without using proper Async techniques, and never getting a response and never timing out at witch point the server just stops responding but doesn't crash.

I would obviously like to find the culprit code and fix the problem, however in the mean time I would like to find a way to automatically restart the server when it stops responding.

To test out solutions locally (since I don't currently know the actual culprit) I have created the following Express route which simulates the exact behavior I'm getting.

```
app.get('/block-block-block', function (req, res){ 
  for(;;) {}
};
```

The question I have is give the above route being hit (which immediately stops the server from responding to anything), is there a way to detect the blockage in node internally and restart or shut down? And if not what is a good solution for checking when the server is not responding and restarting it?

Most searching I have done leads me to tools like [forever](https://github.com/foreverjs/forever) and  [PM2](http://pm2.keymetrics.io/). These work great if your app crashes but I don't really see any fuctionality for restarting when an app is radomley blocking.

Comment: I'm surprised that the popular `forever` script does not support some sort of wellness test on the server (like regularly pinging a test route) to detect this type of issue.  It apparently only detects process crashes.  What you are asking for does seem like a typical thing to want to deploy in production.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I figured out how to solve this using native Node functionality. Migg's answer was good and lead me in the right direction, but it still doesn't show how to automatically restart when the event loop is completely blocked.

The trick is to use Node's native [child_process](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html) module and the [fork method](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_fork_modulepath_args_options) to start the server from another node instance and have that instance ping the server for responses, restarting it when it's stuck. This is similar to how Forever and PM2 work. It's hard to believe there's not a simple way to implement this with either of those libraries, but this is how you can do it naively.

I have commented this code heavily to point out what everything is doing. Also note that I am using ES2015's [Arrow Functions.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) Go read about them if you're not familiar.

```
var fork = require('child_process').fork;
var server, heartbeat; 

function startServer () {
  console.log('Starting server');
  server = fork('server');

  //when the server goes down restart it
  server.on('close', (code) => {
    startServer();
  });

  //when server sends a heartbeat message save it
  server.on('message', (message) => {
    heartbeat = message ? message.heartbeat : null;
  });

  //ask the server for a heartbeat
  server.send({request: 'heartbeat'});

  //wait 5 seconds and check if the server responded
  setTimeout(checkHeartbeat, 5000);
}

function checkHeartbeat() {
  if(heartbeat) {
    console.log('Server is alive');

    //clear the heart beat and send request for a new one
    heartbeat = null; 
    server.send({request: 'heartbeat'});

    //set another hearbeat check
    setTimeout(checkHeartbeat, 5000);

  } else {
    console.log('Server looks stuck...killing');
    server.kill();
  }
}

startServer();
```

Be sure to change out server.js with whatever Node app you want to run.

Now on your server add the following to respond to the heartbeat request.

```
//listen and respond to heartbeat request from parent
process.on('message', (message) => {
  if(message && message.request === 'heartbeat') {
    process.send({heartbeat: 'thump'});
  }
});
```

Finally add a timeout to test that it works (not for production!)

```
//block the even loop after 30 seconds 
setTimeout(() => {
  for(;;){}
}, 30000);
```

Comment: Also this is actually a implementation of the answer @ben-glasser gave.

Comment: For the server.kill(); line (server looks stuck killing), should you restart it too with a startServer(); command under it? Or is this already picked up where server.kill() will automatically call server.on('close', (code) => { startServer(); });

Comment: You could do that. I believe when I did this I had an external service like PM2 or Nodemon, or in this case probably a PASS that would restart it automatically when it went down. Depending on your use case it might be a good idea to do it yourself.

Answer (score 4):

First of all you should try to find the problems in the code by reviewing it.

### Memory Leaks

For the running app you should use `pm2`. It has a setting to restart the app based on too much memory consumption. Directly [from the docs](http://pm2.keymetrics.io/docs/usage/monitoring/#max-memory-restart):

```
pm2 start big-array.js --max-memory-restart 20M
```

Or using an `ecosystem.json`:

```
{
    "max_memory_restart" : "20M"
}
```

There are also [several](https://strongloop.com/strongblog/node-js-performance-tip-of-the-week-memory-leak-diagnosis/) [great](http://blog.yld.io/2015/08/10/debugging-memory-leaks-in-node-js-a-walkthrough/) [articles](https://github.com/felixge/node-memory-leak-tutorial) about debugging memory leaks in node.js to find online. There is even a [module that reports leaks](https://www.npmjs.com/package/memwatch) which we used in the early days. This is too big a subject to fill it in here.

### Blocking Event Loop / Infinite Loops

You can instrument your app to report the responsiveness of the event loop. So if some code blocks the loop for too long you can programmatically terminate the process. You will have to look at [`process.nextTick`](https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_process_nexttick_callback_arg).

You can introduce a measurement that for example calls `process.nextTick` every X seconds, and if it then takes more than some defined time, send `process.exit(1)` to terminate the process and let `pm2` restart it.

The upside of this would be that your app runs most of the time. The downside would be that all users with open connections would get no answer when `process.exit` is called.

### Debugging

To find memory leaks and other problems in the running code you should dive into https://www.joyent.com/developers/node/debug. There is a whole section about MDB which will help you find the problems, but it will take some time and getting used to it. All of this is too much information to not link to it here.

Best of luck with your app!

Comment: If the app is truly hung, not just slow, then your idea to reapeatedly call `process.nextTick()` and measure its responsiveness will not work.  A single threaded app that's hung does not get to do anything else while its hung.  You'd have to monitor from outside the nodejs thread to detect and kill a hung nodejs app.

Comment: Yes thats true, if it really uses the CPU on an infinite loop or recursion there is not much you can do from inside the app. But if it is just blocking the event loop for too long this would work. Hopefully it would leak memory while looping infinitely and `pm2` max memory restart will do the job.

Comment: This answer is good, and instructive. I've been looking into these. @jfriend00 does speak to the heart of my question though. What are good ways to restart in the case of my example where the thread is just completely stuck.  I'll try experimenting with process.next.tick as you suggested. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I have run into this problem once or twice and the answer has always been to handroll a stand alone monitoring service which sends requests to an endpoint at regular intervals.  After so many failed or timed out requests the service will then restart the server.

Its not with out drawbacks however.  The most obvious being that your application has to fail or hit some threshold before being restarted.  That means that it could be down in production for minutes or even hours before a restart depending on your thresholds.  however the alternative is to wait for consumers of the application to start complaining which probably sucks worse since they are most likely your customers.

Comment: That actually crossed my mind. In this case the app is running on Cloud Foundry, so I'll need to figure out a way to use the cli tool through scripts somehow, or figure out if there is a way to configure something like that on the platform.

Answer (score 0):

The common problem why node dies is if we did not handle promise properly, We have to handle promise rejection.

So whenever you are making async call always use try and catch block to handle promise rejection.